# How to print class object data?

Tags: python

I can't get the data within each ticket object to print. What am I doing wrong? I've never used `__dict__` beofre but do I need to? Output I am getting is

```
t1 = Ticket_1()
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'Ticket_1', 'Ticket_2', and 'Ticket_3'
```

Code:

```
class Ticket: #creates ticket and makes a count of each ticket created

    counter = 2000 # static field counter + 2000
    counter += 1
    ticket_number = counter

    def __init__(self, Ticket_1, Ticket_2, Ticket_3):
        self.Ticket_1 = Ticket_1()
        self.Ticket_2 = Ticket_2()
        self.Ticket_3 = Ticket_3()

class Ticket_1(Ticket):

    def ticketVariables(self, creator_name, staff_id, email, issue):
        creator_name = "martha"
        staff_id = "MARTHAT"
        email = "martha@whitecliffe.co.nz"
        issue = "monitor is broken"

        ticket_list = []
        ticket_list.append(ticket_number)
        ticket_list.append(creator_name)
        ticket_list.append(staff_id)
        ticket_list.append(email)
        ticket_list.append(issue)

    def display(self):   
        print("Ticket Number: " + ticket_list[0])
        print("Ticket Creator: " + ticket_list[1])
        print("Staff ID: " + ticket_list[2])
        print("Email Address: " + ticket_list[3])
        print("Description: " + ticket_list[4])

class Ticket_2(Ticket):

    def ticketVariables(self, creator_name, staff_id, email, issue):
        creator_name = "Not Specified"
        staff_id = "PAULG"
        email = "Not Specified"
        issue = "need to change password"

        ticket_list = []
        ticket_list.append(ticket_number)
        ticket_list.append(creator_name)
        ticket_list.append(staff_id)
        ticket_list.append(email)
        ticket_list.append(issue)

    def display(self):   
        print("Ticket Number: " + ticket_list[0])
        print("Ticket Creator: " + ticket_list[1])
        print("Staff ID: " + ticket_list[2])
        print("Email Address: " + ticket_list[3])
        print("Description: " + ticket_list[4])

class Ticket_3(Ticket):

    def ticketVariables(self, creator_name, staff_id, email, issue):
        creator_name = "Not Specified"
        staff_id = "CARLH"
        email = "carlhemmingway@whitecliffe.co.nz"
        issue = "wifi isn't working"

        ticket_list = []
        ticket_list.append(ticket_number)
        ticket_list.append(creator_name)
        ticket_list.append(staff_id)
        ticket_list.append(email)
        ticket_list.append(issue)

    def display(self):   
        print("Ticket Number: " + ticket_list[0])
        print("Ticket Creator: " + ticket_list[1])
        print("Staff ID: " + ticket_list[2])
        print("Email Address: " + ticket_list[3])
        print("Description: " + ticket_list[4])

class main:
  
    t1 = Ticket_1()
    t2 = Ticket_2()
    t3 = Ticket_3()
    myobj = Ticket(t1, t2, t3)

    t1.display()
    t2.display()
    t3.display()
```

Clearly for now, I'm just trying to print the information within each ticket object, but also not sure if I should be using **init** to define those variables or not...?

Comment: If you want calls like `Ticket_1()` to be valid with no parameters, then the relevant `__init__()` method must not have any required parameters (other than `self`).

Comment: It seems you are trying to create different classes where you actually should make several instances of the same class.

Comment: Since `ticket1`, `ticket2` and `ticket3` all define the same functionality you only need one class to hold all the functionality. All the fields may be set by using the parameters of the functions instead of setting them individually in each body. You're issue is that you'd have to define a `_init_` in each class to override the `_init_` in your base since your base requires each `ticket` in its `_init_`. Try looking at a [Python classes guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-comprehensive-guide-for-classes-in-python-e6bb72a25a5e) for more help.